# Subquery to select data from same table as a crosstab

Tags: oracle, pivot

I want to create a report from a single table and use each distinct column of a table as a separate column and cause of this i can reduce amount of three rows to one!
[the original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFmFy.png)

these underlined columns to be as a column headers to there related item_value_afs!
 the result should be like this!
[the wanted result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC5oI.png)

my second query is not correct please help me in this problem!
first query to show all

```
select reg_no
item_no,
reg_date,
tax_decription,
ITEM_VALUE_AFS
from
sigtasad.mv_customs_report;
```

second query/ wanted query:

```
select distinct reg_no,
item_no,
reg_date,
(
  select sum(code_tax_amount) 
  from sigtasad.d_customs_load ss
  where ss.reg_no=e.reg_no  
) import_duty,
(
  select sum(code_tax_amount)
  from sigtasad.d_customs_load ss 
  where ss.reg_no=e.reg_no  
) as "Profit Tax For Import",
(
  select sum(code_tax_amount)
  from sigtasad.d_customs_load ss
  where ss.reg_no=e.reg_no
) as "Import Tax With license 2%" 
from sigtasad.d_customs_load e 
where rownum<100;
```

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting an error, or incorrect results?

Comment: @bbrumm I Got incorrect result bro!
please see the images then you will know my problem....

Comment: MySQL? Oracle? (Don't say BOTH - I won't believe you.) Then - what version of the database? For example in Oracle, if version is 11.1 or higher, this can be done with the `PIVOT` operator. (Search the site for hundreds of similar questions, with hundreds of examples of how it's done.)

Comment: I would suggest the PIVOT function. But are all three of your columns meant to be the same?

Comment: @mathguy I have used Oracle 10g!

Comment: Then see MT0's answer in the question I just linked yours to.

Comment: thanks @mathguy your link to the duplicated question works!

Comment: thanks @bbrumm yes PIVOT is worked to me!